# Swift 2.0 - Get user details from firebase

Tags: swift, model, firebase

I'm new to Swift and Firebase, and would like to know how to get a users details from Firebase by the userId.

I have the Firebase 'uid' stored in NSUserDefauls.

I have a user Model class like the following;

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

class User: NSObject {

var id: String?
var username: String?
var email: String?
var yogaLevel : Enums.Difficulty?


init(id: String, username: String, email: String){

    self.id = id
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
}


override init(){
    super.init()
}
}
```

I have a dataservie class that makes the relevant calls to Firebase;

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class DataService{

static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)")
private var _USER_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/users")

var BASE_REF: Firebase {
    return _BASE_REF
}

var USER_REF: Firebase {
    return _USER_REF
}

var CURRENT_USER_REF: Firebase {
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}


func createNewAccount(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>) {

    // A new user is created:
    USER_REF.childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(user)
}



}
```

I also have a manager class, that I would like to contains methods that return the users details.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserManager: NSObject {

static var currentUser = User()

class func getCurrentUserDetails() -> User{

    // Attach a closure to read the data at our posts reference
    DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_REF.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        currentUser.username = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("username"))
        currentUser.email = String(snapshot.value.objectForKey("email"))
        currentUser.id = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid"))

        print(String(currentUser.username) + " " + String(currentUser.email))

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print("UserManager class - getCurrentUserDetails error: " + String(error.description))
    })

    return currentUser
}
```

}

I'd like advise on how I will create a function in the manager class the returns a 'user' that is populated from Firebase using the 'uid' I have stored. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Please comment if you require more information, or more code.

Comment: If your data is secured with the security rules you might need authUser()

Comment: @CodyWeaver it looks like my problem is not what I first anticipated. I can return the data with the comment code above in the manager class. However, I can't store the data against the user object. Can you advise how I do this in swift (No getters and setters in Swift?)

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code: You probably don't need to store the users uid in the NSUserDefaults as the currently logged in uid is always available from Firebase authData. Second, remember that Firebase is asynchronous so the 'return currentUser' call in the manager class may actually occur *before* the data has been returned in the observeEventType block which may cause the app to crash. There appears to be lot of extraneous code - if you are just looking to get the users node of the current user and populate a user class, it should be about 10 lines of code total.

Comment: I have updated my manager class - Can you advise what I need to do to populate the user class ... @jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty open ended question so my answer is in the form of direction.

The current logged in user uid can be returned directly from Firebase:

```
if self.myRootRef.authData != nil {
    print(ref.authData.uid) // user is authenticated
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

To answer the question(s) assume a Firebase structure of

```
root
  users
     uid_0
       name: "Leroy"
       email: "l.jenkins@ubrs.com"
```

Assume a User class

```
class UserClass: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var uid: String?
}
```

Then, to populate a User class, the following code could be used to call a function

```
self.populateUser("uid_0")
```

here's the function to populate a User class from Firebase and add it to a Users array. That array could then be used to populate a tableView for example.

```
func populateUser(uid: String) {

    let thisUserRef = self.usersRef.childByAppendingPath(uid)

    thisUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("snapshot was null");
        } else {
            let thisUser = UserClass()
            thisUser.name = snapshot.value.objectForKey("name") as? String
            thisUser.email = snapshot.value.objectForKey("email") as? String
            thisUser.uid = uid
            self.Users.append(thisUser)
            print("\(thisUser.name!)")
        }
    })
}
```

self.Users is a class variable array defined thusly

```
var Users = [UserClass]()
```

Note 1: If the variables in your DataService class are global in nature, you can just create a file in your swift project and add them to a structure

```
MyGlobalVars.swift

struct MyGlobals {
    static var rootRef = "app.firebase.com"
    static var usersRef = "app.firebase.com/users"
}
```

Those can be accessed anywhere with

```
print("Global variable:\(MyGlobals.usersRef)")
```

Note 2: As in your Users class, you could just pass the snapshot to the Users class with an init and let it populate itself as well.

thisUser.populateFromSnapshot(snapshot.value)

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge @jay . Hopefully you can help with a problem I have following your route. When I create a new user (sign up) I navigate to my main controller which calls 'populateUser', and for some reason the snapshot is null. IS the due to Firebase being async?

Comment: @CottonSocksBro The process is:  preset login for user, capture their info and attempt to authenticate. When the authentication completes, the code inside the auth block is called. It could pass or fail, so when it's successful, *then* call populate user, and when that's successful (inside the block), *then* navigate to the main controller. You need to ensure your code always allows for Firebase to return it's data within a block, and then based on that returned data, move to the next step. It's hard to wrap your brain around it at first but it will come with time.